# Java - Object value not modified after passing object reference variable to another function

Tags: java, oop

I am passing integer object reference

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Integer x = new Integer(56);
        Integer y = new Integer(34);
        Test1 test = new Test1();
        test.change(x,y);
        System.out.println("Values inside main() after calling change method");
        System.out.println("x :"+ x +"; y :"+y);
    }
    public void change(Integer x1, Integer y1){

        x1 = 45;
        y1 = 1000;
        System.out.println("Values After Modification inside change method");
        System.out.println("x1 :"+ x1 +"; y1 :"+y1);
    }
}
```

but there is no change in value of x and y ??
Please help...Thank you in advance. Here is the output.

```
Values After Modification inside change method
x1 :45; y1 :1000
Values inside main() after calling change method
x :56; y :34
```

Comment: Java is pass by value

Comment: See this http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html

Comment: @Reimeus You mean Java is pass by reference value ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ nope, see duplicate...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the fact that they're immutable is irrelevant. Doing that with a mutable AtomicInteger would not change anything. The OP confuses "mutating an object", and "assigning a new object to a variable".

Comment: @JBNizet: D'oh! `<slaps_own_head>`

Answer (score 1):

Java is always **pass-by-value**.  This means the references passed to the method are actually **copies of the original references**.

Unfortunately, they decided to call pointers references, thus confusing newbies. Because those references are passed by value.